# React Web page turning blank after adding a constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm a React newbie and I was following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/wYpCWwD1oz0) on YouTube, which is at the time of writing this approximately 3 months old.

I got to this phase:
[image: The web is working yet]

However then I ran into a problem. This is a piece of code that works so far:

```
function App() {
  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
    <div className='app'>
      {/* <Sidebar /> This is the const which causes the web to break for some reason */}
      <main className='content'>
        <Topbar />
       {/* <Routes> */}
          {/* <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/classification' element={<Classification />} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/timetable' element={<Timetable />} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/class' element={<Class />} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/profile' element={<Profile />} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/settings' element={<Settings />} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/notifications' element={<Notifications />} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/calendar' element={<Calendar />} /> */}
        {/* </Routes> */}
      </main>
    </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However if I uncomment the `<Sidebar />` the page turns blank. As far as I tried to debug, it doesn't matter if the Sidebar file is empty or not, the page turns blank regardless.

As a React newbie, my knowledge is very limited so I haven't tried much aside of debugging. All I know is that the code in the  file doesn't affect the error in any way. What I expected to happen is a sidebar to appear on the left with a couple of buttons and an image. Instead the page just turned blank. I assume this is not caused by some outdated dependencies since as I said, the code in the Sidebar file doesn't seem to affect this error. My assumption is a logical mistake I can't manage to find.

I'd love to get any sort of help with this. Furthermore, if anyone knows how to write this piece of code differently, with the same functionality (you can see in the linked video tutorial above), I will definitely be looking forward to seeing your advice. Thanks a bunch!

EDIT: This is the Sidebar file:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem } from "react-pro-sidebar";
import { Box, IconButton, Typography, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";
import { tokens } from "../../theme";
import HomeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HomeOutlined";
import PeopleOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PeopleOutlined";
import ContactsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ContactsOutlined";
import ReceiptOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ReceiptOutlined";
import PersonOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlined";
import CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CalendarTodayOutlined";
import HelpOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutlineOutlined";
import BarChartOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/BarChartOutlined";
import PieChartOutlineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PieChartOutlineOutlined";
import TimelineOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/TimelineOutlined";
import MenuOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MenuOutlined";
import MapOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MapOutlined";

const Item = ({ title, to, icon, selected, setSelected }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  return (
    <MenuItem
      active={selected === title}
      style={{
        color: colors.grey[100],
      }}
      onClick={() => setSelected(title)}
      icon={icon}
    >
      <Typography>{title}</Typography>
      <Link to={to} />
    </MenuItem>
  );
};

const Sidebar = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Dashboard");

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        "& .pro-sidebar-inner": {
          background: `${colors.primary[400]} !important`,
        },
        "& .pro-icon-wrapper": {
          backgroundColor: "transparent !important",
        },
        "& .pro-inner-item": {
          padding: "5px 35px 5px 20px !important",
        },
        "& .pro-inner-item:hover": {
          color: "#868dfb !important",
        },
        "& .pro-menu-item.active": {
          color: "#6870fa !important",
        },
      }}
    >
      <ProSidebar collapsed={isCollapsed}>
        <Menu iconShape="square">
          {/* LOGO AND MENU ICON */}
          <MenuItem
            onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}
            icon={isCollapsed ? <MenuOutlinedIcon /> : undefined}
            style={{
              margin: "10px 0 20px 0",
              color: colors.grey[100],
            }}
          >
            {!isCollapsed && (
              <Box
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
                ml="15px"
              >
                <Typography variant="h3" color={colors.grey[100]}>
                  Project Romeo
                </Typography>
                <IconButton onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}>
                  <MenuOutlinedIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Box>
            )}
          </MenuItem>

          {!isCollapsed && (
            <Box mb="25px">
              <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <img
                  alt="profile-user"
                  width="100px"
                  height="100px"
                  src={`../../assets/user.png`} // Database here for user profile picture or default picture?
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", borderRadius: "50%" }}
                />
              </Box>
              <Box textAlign="center">
                <Typography
                  variant="h2"
                  color={colors.grey[100]}
                  fontWeight="bold"
                  sx={{ m: "10px 0 0 0" }}
                >
                  Vojtěch Král
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="h5" color={colors.greenAccent[500]}>
                  Project Romeo Developer
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          )}

          <Box paddingLeft={isCollapsed ? undefined : "10%"}>
            <Item
              title="Dashboard"
              to="/"
              icon={<HomeOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />

            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color={colors.grey[300]}
              sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
            >
              Data
            </Typography>
            <Item
              title="Manage Team"
              to="/team"
              icon={<PeopleOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Contacts Information"
              to="/contacts"
              icon={<ContactsOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Invoices Balances"
              to="/invoices"
              icon={<ReceiptOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />

            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color={colors.grey[300]}
              sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
            >
              Pages
            </Typography>
            <Item
              title="Profile Form"
              to="/form"
              icon={<PersonOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Calendar"
              to="/calendar"
              icon={<CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="FAQ Page"
              to="/faq"
              icon={<HelpOutlineOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />

            <Typography
              variant="h6"
              color={colors.grey[300]}
              sx={{ m: "15px 0 5px 20px" }}
            >
              Charts
            </Typography>
            <Item
              title="Bar Chart"
              to="/bar"
              icon={<BarChartOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Pie Chart"
              to="/pie"
              icon={<PieChartOutlineOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Line Chart"
              to="/line"
              icon={<TimelineOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
            <Item
              title="Geography Chart"
              to="/geography"
              icon={<MapOutlinedIcon />}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
          </Box>
        </Menu>
      </ProSidebar>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: if the sidebar file is empty, it's not a valid React component. can you post the code of Sidebar that doesn't work ?

Comment: Sure, I will. The file is not empty, but I tried it with a clean file as well to make sure the problem isn't in the Sidebar file.

Comment: Just clone the repo from the demo and run it github.com/ed-roh/react-admin-dashboard.git - you should find your error. The app does work and you should be able to compare the code to find out why

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to find the mistake. But I will probably have to do what you suggested.